# Need To Convert IO.FileStream Code To Get File From Server Instead Of Local

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert this vb.net code to get this file from the server instead of the local hard drive.

```
Using inputPdfStream As IO.Stream = New IO.FileStream("C:\Users\XXX\Documents\123.pdf", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)
```

Something like this (obviously this doesn't work):

```
Using inputPdfStream As IO.Stream = New IO.FileStream("http://www.website.com/images/123.pdf", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `WebRequest` class instead of the `FileStream`:

```
Using inputPdfStream As IO.Stream = WebRequest.Create("http://www.website.com/images/123.pdf").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()
```